# BeautifulSoup HTTP Error 403: Forbidden - Not Sure Why

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I the following python program that when I execute it, I get an **HTTP 403: Forbidden** error.

Here's the code:

```py
import os 
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#import urllib.request
#from urllib.request import request, urlopen
from urllib import request
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import time
import openpyxl


for a in range(0,len(symbols),1):
    """
        Attempt to get past the Forbidden error message.
    """
    #ua = UserAgent()
    url = "https://fintel.io/ss/us/" + symbols[a]
    """
       test urls:
                 https://fintel.io/ss/us/A
                 https://fintel.io/ss/us/BBY'
                 https://fintel.io/ss/us/WMT'
    """

    print("Extracting Values for " + symbols[a] + ".")
    header = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36'
        }
    try:
            page_request = request.Request(url, headers=header)
            page = request.urlopen(page_request)
            #old page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser", from_encoding="iso-8859-1")
```

The result I'm getting:

```
Extracting Values for A.
HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
Extracting Values for BBY.
HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
Extracting Values for WMT.
HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Any suggestions on how to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

That's not a BeautifulSoup specific error, the website you're trying to scrape is probably protected by Cloudflare's anti bot page. You can try using [cfscrape](https://github.com/Anorov/cloudflare-scrape.git) to bypass this.

Answer (score 0):

Your complaint is with Request, rather than with beautifulsoup.
The website refuses to serve your requests.

When I use that UA it works fine, I receive a `200` document:

```
$ wget -U 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36' -S https://fintel.io/ss/us/BBY
```

But then again, even using UA of 'Wget/1.20.3 (darwin19.0.0)' works just fine:

```
$ wget -S https://fintel.io/ss/us/BBY
```

Looks like you've been doing excessive crawling,
and your IP is now being blocked by the webserver.